# android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

Tags: android

I am getting this expcetion:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1806)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1617)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1401)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2458)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but the problem is that I can not find the root of the problem. Where exactly and what that means?

And why widget, i don't have any widget!

CODE:

Not sure if here:

```
public class MyListPreference extends ListPreference {

    public MyListPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        TextView dialogTitle = (TextView)super.onCreateDialogView();

        if (dialogTitle != null) {
            // Dialog
            dialogTitle.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.category_background));
            dialogTitle.setPadding(10, 4, 4, 4);

            // Text
            dialogTitle.setTextSize(14);
            dialogTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            dialogTitle.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_background));

            dialogTitle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
        return dialogTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: show code also it will help us find the problem where it is .

Comment: You are using an Adapter in which you are setting the LayoutParams of the view returned by the getView function to ViewGroup.LayoutParams instead of AbsListView.LayoutParams. But then again this is only a guess.

Comment: I add code where maybe can be error, but i am not sure if is correct

Comment: show imports in ListPreference

Comment: can anyone help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
dialogTitle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Here you're replacing existing layout params of correct type `AbsListView.LayoutParams` with more generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Layout params type is that of the parent container of the view.

If you need to modify existing layout params, access them with `getLayoutParams()`, modify it, and call `requestLayout()` to notify that the layout has changed.

Example. Instead of

```
fooView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(123, 456));
```

do

```
LayoutParams lp = fooView.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 123;
lp.height = 456;
fooView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I don't undesratnd completely what you mean? Can you give me example? Thank you

Comment: getLayoutParams() won't work if you are trying to set the size before you add the view to a layout, such as if you are extending the view.  Then you have to discover that the underlying implementation is android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams and instantiate that:  setLayoutParams(new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(w, h)).  This completely breaks encapsulation (exposing the internal implementation of LayoutParams) and is an API bug.

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Comment: "Layout params type is that of the parent container of the view." - this is the golden statement here. Whichever layout you are trying to set params has to have params as per his parent. (That's what I think the problem is).

Comment: I ran into the same class cast exception when returning a view in Adapter.getView with ViewGroup.LayoutParams. However I'd like to mention that the class cast exception seems to happen on older API level (I tested API 19). On newer API level (tested on 22), there is no exception at all. So the underlying implementation seems to be able to deal with returning a view with ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(123, 456));
```

with

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new  android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(123, 456));
```

this worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this solution offers anything unique above what has already been suggested then please explain it. But in general try to avoid code only answers since they do not offer enough long term value to the community. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to code inside `ListView`.

**In conclusion, We should set only `AbsListView.LayoutParams` to `View` if it is used directly as child in `ListView`.**

Following is the reason.

In `onMeasure()` of `ListView`:

```java
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
//...
    // Lay out child directly against the parent measure spec so that
    // we can obtain exected minimum width and height.
    measureScrapChild(child, 0, widthMeasureSpec, heightSize);
//...
}

private void measureScrapChild(View child, int position, int widthMeasureSpec, int heightHint) {
    LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    if (p == null) {
        p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
        child.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
    //...
}
```

So if an item view already has `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, it will not be override to `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. However, in `setupChild`, `layoutChildren` and many other methods, `ListView` always casts `LayoutParams` of item view into `AbsListView.LayoutParams`. Such as

```java
private void setupChild(View child, int position, int y, boolean flowDown, int childrenLeft,
            boolean selected, boolean isAttachedToWindow) {
    //...

    // Respect layout params that are already in the view. Otherwise make
    // some up...
    AbsListView.LayoutParams p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    if (p == null) {
        p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    }
    //...
}
```