# LayoutParams type changed at runtime. ClassCastException: ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I try to set layout params programmatically. In my fragment in `onCreate` method, I set LayoutParams of the `ScrollView` and it works. But also, I have an observer and in this observer when some condition is true I change layout params of this `ScrollView` again. But the problem is that the same code which is in `onCreate` doesn't work in an observer. Below is a fragment of `onCreate` method when I set layout params and set an observer. The method which changes layout params is copy-pasted so it is a little strange why it is working and a milliseconds after doesn't.

**onCreate:**

```
Log.d("Setting height in onCreate method")
binding.scrollRoot.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    binding.txtCars.lineHeight * SIZE + 10
)


cars.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    if (it.size < SIZE)
    {
        Log.d("Setting height in observer method")
        binding.scrollRoot.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            binding.txtCars.lineHeight * (it.size) + 10
        )
    }
    binding.txtCars.text = formatCars(it, requireContext())
})
```

**Logcat:**

```
D/AppDebug: Setting height in onCreate method
D/AppDebug: Setting height in observer method
I/zygote64: Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 25337 in void org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.HTMLSchema.<init>()
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down ViewModel
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fuelmanager, PID: 8034
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6662)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1539)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:823)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:702)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:831)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1638)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7292)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

After research, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045198/android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-abslistview/21045396)

> Here you're replacing existing layout params of correct type `AbsListView.LayoutParams` with more generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Layout params type is that of the parent container of the view.
> If you need to modify existing layout params, access them with `getLayoutParams()`, modify it, and call `requestLayout()` to notify that the layout has changed.

So I made it in that way:

```
Log.d("Setting height in observer method")
val layoutParams = binding.scrollRoot.layoutParams
layoutParams.height = binding.txtCars.lineHeight * (it.size) + 10
```

And it works.

**But my question is how is it possible that type of `ViewGroup`/`ScrollView` LayoutParams changed.** What happened after `onCrete()` that makes this error in the observer?

Comment: When adding a `View` with pre-defined `LayoutParams` to a `ViewGroup`, a check is done to ensure that the `LayoutParams` is a compatible type. If it's not, it will be adjusted, or replaced with a default `LayoutParams`. When you set the `LayoutParams` on that `ScrollView` (which I'm assuming is the root) in `onCreate()`, the `ScrollView` hasn't been added to its parent yet, so the `LayoutParams` gets "fixed". No such check is done after that, however, so when you set an incompatible type later on, you get that Exception.